# (Windows XP) Play sound from both front and rear headphone jacks

Tags: windows, windows-xp, audio, headphones, headphone-jack

Is it possible to configure my computer such that it will play music from both the front and rear headphone jacks?

Comment: I just connected the chassis cables to mobo's pins and it plays from both the front & rear headphone jacks.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is...Why?

Do you have 2 sets of speakers that you want sound from?  If so, wouldnt a splitter (less than $.99) do the trick on the rear headphone jack, making the front of the machine cleaner looking?